# A closure property of a set partition

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics

Let $A$ be a finite set, $k\in\mathbb N$, $\tilde A\subset A^k$ and $\phi: \tilde A\to A$ be a map.

Consider the following property a set partition $P$ of $A$ might have:
$$
\forall B_1,\dotsc,B_k\in P\; \exists B\in P\; \forall (b_1,\dotsc,b_k)\in (B_1\times\dotsb\times B_k)\cap\tilde A :\phi(b_1,\dotsc,b_k)\in B. 
$$
Put differently: the image of $\phi(B_1,\dotsc,B_k)$ is contained in a single block.

I would like to know whether this notion has (in some sense) a name, and whether there is a nice way to compute, given a set partition $Q$ of $A$, the finest set partition coarser than $Q$ having the above mentioned property.

Comment: @SamHopkins quite right, thank you!  The question comes from a practical computer problem, which I tried to abstract, and I made a mistake, obviously.  I'll edit the condition.

Comment: @bof, yes, thank you!

Comment: I think the equivalence relation corresponding to the partition $P$ would be considered a [congruence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation) on the structure $(A,\phi)$ in the sense of universal algebra.